# How do I find word in an array and find how many characters later does it appear in the array in java?

Tags: java

So I have the following program where I am able to get user's input, reverse the input and find out how long it is (character wise) but I do not know how to find a keyword in the user's input (which I have tuned it into an array) and don't know how to tell after how many characters later does the keyword begin after.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter The String (With Space Separating The Words):");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        String usrInput = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        String output[] = usrInput.split(" ");
        String arrayOutput = "";
        for (int i = output.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arrayOutput += output[i];
            if (i != 0) {
                arrayOutput += " ";
            }
        }


        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("You entered:\n");
        for(String j : output) { System.out.println(j); }
        System.out.println("\nIt is "  + usrInput.length() + " characters long");
        System.out.println("You entered " + output.length + " words.");
        System.out.println("The reversed string is: " + arrayOutput);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need an array for what you are asking. Look through the built-in methods of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Especially [`String#contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`String#indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at String docs. From what you are trying to describe i assume you will need `indexOf` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Be sure to check right java version docs for your need.